# Missing artifact com.splunk:splunk:jar:1.6.0.0

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, splunk

My pom doesn't download this dependancy `splunk:jar:1.6.0.0` though the remote repositories does host this jar.

Also, my IDE doesn't have internet/proxy issues while downloading other maven repositories.

Below is the mvn pom :

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

            <groupId>com.jl</groupId>
            <artifactId>p1p2checklist</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>

            <name>p1p2checklist</name>
            <description>P1P2 project for John Lewis Partnership</description>
<dependencies>
<dependency>

                    <groupId>com.splunk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>splunk</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>splunk-artifactory</id>
                    <name>Splunk Releases</name>
                    <url>http://splunk.artifactoryonline.com/splunk/ext-releases-local</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>

        </project>
```

The remote repository url ([link](http://splunk.artifactoryonline.com/splunk/ext-releases-local)) mentioned in above pom does contain the jar, however I'm not sure why the jar isn't downloaded.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might have added the Splunk dependency before adding the repository information to your POM. Maven keeps track of failed downloads and does not retry until a certain time period has passed. Try deleting the splunk directory from your local Maven repository (~/.m2/repository/com/splunk) and then try again.

Comment: Yeah, I had the splunk dependency before and removed to have this downloaded from remote repository. As a workaround, I installed this jar in my local mvn repository. Thanks for letting me know about the failed downloads, will give a try.
Thanks

Comment: Your closing `<dependencies>` tag is missing the slash, it should be `</ dependencies>`

Comment: @Shakeel have edited the question. My Pom syntax is correct. It's not a syntax related issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing dependencies around your dependency tag.

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.splunk</groupId>
        <artifactId>splunk</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0.0</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: actually, dependencies is present in my pom. I removed it here.

Answer (score 1):

This error encountered because splunk:jar:1.6.0.0 not found at http://splunk.artifactoryonline.com/splunk/ext-releases-local so please update it to https://splunk.artifactoryonline.com/artifactory/ext-releases-local at nifi-splunk-bundle's POM.xml file.

```
<repository>
            <id>splunk</id>
            <name>Splunk Artifactory</name>
            <url>http://splunk.artifactoryonline.com/artifactory/ext-releases-local/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
```